# Move button with Keyboard, Swift

Tags: swift, user-interface, uiviewcontroller, keyboard, uibutton

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        if self.textView.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            let height = keyboardSize.height
            self.textButton.frame.origin.y -= height
            Log.debug("height: \(height)")
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
     if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

    if self.textButton.frame.origin.y != 0 {
        let height = keyboardSize.height
        self.textButton.frame.origin.y += height
        Log.debug("height: \(height)")
    }
}
}
```

I have this 2 function called with the proper observer.
The problem is that the height of keyboard change after the second keyboard show. This is what happened =>

- KeyBoard show => height 346
- Keyboard hide => height 346
- Keyboard show => height 243
- keyboard hide => height 346
- Keyboard show => height 243

This is where I set my button:

```
textButton.frame = CGRect(x: textView.frame.width - 95, y: textView.frame.height , width: 70, height: 70)
```

And this is my button function called from ViewDidLoad()

```
 @objc func crossButtonTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
    self.textView.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

P.s. What If I want keyboard to show on button click and hide on second button click?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly if you want to add buttons that will stick above the keyboard i recommend using "UIToolbar".

and about your P.S its pretty simple:

```
@objc func crossButtonTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
    self.textView.isFirstResponder ? self.textView.resignFirstResponder() : 
    self.textView.becomeFirstResponder() 
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the P.S. !!

And thank you for the UIToolbar advice, but I find quiete strange that behavior of the keyboard ... I would like to fix it like it is. I mean why should the keyboard lose -103height on second tap

Comment: try changing "keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey" to "keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey" i think it should do the trick

Comment: You are my hero